# Storing regex with '^' and '$' inside constant

Tags: perl

**I revised my code and realized I stored the regex inside constant and then used the latter's value for the variable**

I'm trying to store a regular expression inside <s>variable</s> constant using the qr// operator. Everything is fine except for '^' and '$'. I need them to match beginning-of-line and end-of-line respectively.

```
use constant REGEX_LINE    => qr/\^(\s*)(.*)\$/;
my $rx = REGEX_LINE;
```

Printing $rx reveals that it contains some addiotional stuff:

```
(?^:^(\s*)(.*)$)
```

Of course now the regex doesn't match my data

Comment: Works for me too 5.18

Comment: Works for me with 5.14  Why don't you show an example of the string you are trying to match.

Comment: Printing can show "_additional stuff_", it's for display.  What do you mean by "_doesn't match my data_"?  The regex you show is hard to test, it just matches any and every thing (including nothing).

Comment: The question was misleading, sorry guys. The problem is the constant

Comment: You just changed your regex, adding escapes to `^` and `$`, which originally weren't there.  Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: I just tested without escapes and it works. I was mislead by myself o_O

Comment: @TichomirMitkov  (1) Remove those escapes, you don't need them.  The regex should work fine, const or not. (2) Come up with a more testable example. (3) Show what fails.  //  For me, it just works, as it should.

Comment: That code does not produce that output!

Comment: We need to see some code that actually fails.  You've described failing code, but we haven't see any.  Please edit your question to include a complete program that will let us see the problem in action.

Comment: @AndyLester  I think the problem was misreported and got clarified for the OP, per their comment above -- "_I just tested without escapes and it works._"  This question should probably go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect `^` and `$` to match start and end of line,

- don't escape them (or else they will match `^` and `$`), and
- use `/m` (or else they will match the start and end of the string).

```
use constant REGEX_LINE => qr/^(\s*)(.*)$/m;
```

Answer (score -2):

Add escape character(\) before $ symbol otherwise it will consider as a part of variable

Comment: no it won't, when it's at the end of the regex. It's seen as the end-of-string anchor.

Comment: Quite the opposite!!! He needs to remove the `\ ` before `^` and `$`.